# Magento 2 frontend error after installing an extension

Tags: magento2

Hello when I add an extension to Magento 2 my front-end disappears, but at the back end everything is fine and that extension is working.

I have tried increasing the PHP memory limit in PHP.ini sample and run the command PHP bin/Magento setup: static-content: deployment but the front-end is not working. So please let me know how to solve this issue.

[image: Please check front-end pic]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Probably the extension you're adding has errors? Do you see anything in the Javascript console in the browser developer tools?

Comment: @ peedee hello sir there is nothing in Javascript console. so plz let me know what to do next. Thanks!

Comment: Please tell me which steps you had followed and which extension you had been installed ?

Comment: @SunnyRathod i uploaded the extension then run the commaand php bin/magento set:upgrade and php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy but no changes on frontend. i had alo enabled developer mode but no changes. But when i  i renamed php.ini.sample to php.ini then on frontend there is this error msg - Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on null in /home/*******/public_html/app/design/frontend/Ced/ced/Magent‌​o_Theme/templates/ht‌​ml/header.phtml on line 162. I got this in system log file - main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog sidebar' sale sidebar and many more.

Comment: @SunnyRathod i am using ceedcommerce csmarketplace for magento 2 and whenever i install this extension my frontend disappears.

Comment: you have 2 option either you debug that extension or else ask support for that extension. I can not say what is exact error.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, follow the steps given below:

Step 1- First flush/clean the cache of your magento

```
        For Cache flush using command
        magento cache:flush 

        For Clean flush using command
        magento cache:clean

       OR
```

You can also clean and flush cache types in the Magento Admin. Go to System > Tools > Cache Management. Flush Cache Storage is equivalent to magento cache:flush. Flush Magento Cache is equivalent to magento cache:clean.

Step 2- Delete the content of static folder. To delete, follow the given path
MangentoDir > pub > static.

Step 3- Run the static view files deployment tool 
/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Step 4- Go to the MangetoDir > pub > error and rename the local.xml.sample file to local.xml.

After going through these 4 steps, refresh the frontend page in browser to get the front-end.

Comment: hello sir i have followed every steps but nothing woked. There is no changes on frontend. sir plz help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rishav, By using the above steps, You can see the exact error in the front end. After having a look at the error, work according to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

always works for me when no resources are available

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Might be your frontend running in some other language so you need to need to deploy the content on that specific language as well like below example :

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US ro_RO
```

For language code, you can open the console of browser & look for any url which are failing to load, in that url you will be able to find the language code in which your frontend is working.